# What are the differences between Hinduism and Buddhism?

Tags: comparative-religion, hinduism

Hinduism is similar to Buddhism, but both are different.

Many people think that Buddhism is derived from Hinduism, so it is similar to Hinduism.

What are the differences between Hinduism & Buddhism?

Comment: there is also [Relationship between Buddhism, Hinduism and Yoga?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/123/relationship-between-buddhism-hinduism-and-yoga)

Comment: If this is a duplicate answer, why not post a link to the original post so we can read the information there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I found Hinduism was the religion, Siddhartha was raised in. Hinduism has a vast arrays of Gods, Like Vishnu, Shiva, Krishna, an so on. Buddhism to my understanding Has no God in it. The difference starts there. Hindus have many gods and Buddhism has none, although it can become difficult when comparing Bodhisattva's an Buddha's an the dwellers of the celestial world depending on your Buddhist tradition.

Buddha concentrated more on not worrying about the divine beings. But to worry about fixing your self.Basically in the aspect of Karma you decide for yourself what happens to you. There is no judge to your life but yourself. You rebirth higher or lower depending on your Karma ( depending on the Buddhist tradition ). You are the master of your self, an so focusing on yourself you alone can help yourself. You do not worry about appeasing deities. Or the origin in which you came from, an what lies beyond today. To be in the present an to judge according to your own understanding seems to be the Buddhist method.

So a religion that focuses on the worship of their deities, the practices of the deities, the rewards an punishments from the deities. All this becomes distractful an can cause great deal of suffering when you are trying very hard to appease a certain deity. An in Hinduism there are vastly many of them. There are many gurus that teach very different an strange customs. Some traditions still perform animal sacrifice ( Kali )

Buddha ultimately walked away from the Brahmin teachers, an the way of Hinduism, as he did not see the path leading to happiness. He saw that people became ascetics an starved them selves and pierce there bodies in harsh ways to prove the devotion to their gods. Buddha once tried these methods to find enlightenment, but almost starved to death an realized, if he had died nothing would have been gained from doing these things. So he focused on how to find true happiness, an that was through insightful meditations an begin teachings the Dharma.

The main difference is the Deities, the customs an practices of both can become mingled as they have a similar basis on some things. But really the focus is what makes them different. To focus on a god or to focus on your self as a "god". Hopefully this helpful in some way.

Comment: sorry for the downvote. a lot here is factually incorrect. Siddhartha was not raised in Hinduism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_Vedic_religion also Buddhism is not without gods, there are enough questions on this site dealing with that topic.

Comment: Buddha Rejected the Concpect of a Creator God. So what are you referring to? 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_in_Buddhism

If you are refering to Devas, they are not completely considered as Gods more like higher realm beings, since they too are said to suffer, die an reborn. What would you consider as a God would help me understand what you mean by gods in buddhism. Here is the Devas link to clarify if you are referring to them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deva_%28Buddhism%29

Comment: Also here is link talking about Buddhas rejection of the Vedas, The Hinduism to help calrify http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha_in_Hinduism
here some q an a on it https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070724233426AAH5FTY an here is another for help too http://www.answers.com/Q/What_parts_of_Hinduism_did_Siddhartha_accept_and_what_parts_did_he_reject

Comment: From now on I will be posting references so that I will not have my answers criticized. If you dont like what Wikipida says then dont fuss at me for receiving my answers from it an helping others to understand.I answer from what I know if I need help I search for it. This is what I found.

Comment: I forgot a link the connection of reincarnation from Hinduism that helped Siddhartha understand rebirth. http://www.answers.com/Q/How_did_the_idea_of_reincarnation_from_Hinduism_lead_to_Siddhartha_Gautama%27s_forming_of_Buddhism

Answer (score 1):

Buddha practiced all the religions of the day and could not find awakening from suffering. The Hindu faith rests more on ceremony and ritual than some methods of Buddhism.
Buddhists do not have to believe anything or worship anything, just wake up.
Disclaimer, I am not a Hindu, but they do have many rituals and ceremonies.
If you find a path that works for you, follow it until it is no longer usable, then find the next leg in the journey, even if it means becoming a lay practitioner.